# mainLayout in onCreateView is not working for 4.4 & lower

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I have below in one of my project

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        Log.d("errrrr", "making mainlayout-1");
        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, null);
        Log.d("errrrr", "making mainlayout-1.1");
```

Also I have below in inStart

```
if (mainLayout==null) {
    Log.d("errrr", "22--mainlayout is not okay");
} else {
    Log.d("errrr", "33--mainlayout is okay");
}
mloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Below is the output for Android 4.2

```
D/errrrr: making mainlayout-1
D/errrr: 22--mainlayout is okay
```

Now as mainLayout is null, `mloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` is crashing calling NullPointerException.

This is because in createView I have below.

```
mloading = (ProgressBar) mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
```

But as `mainLayout` is null, nothing is defined.

Any idea what is going wrong?

***Note: This is working fine for OS 5.0 & above***

---

### Edit 1

***Below is the exception***

*E/HomeFragment  onCreate>>LineNumber: 162: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView*

Home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_cats"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#ff343431">

        <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
            android:id="@+id/lst_newsCats"
            style="@style/TwoWayView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#ff343431"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pager_urgent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel_cats"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/img_slider"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#ff9e9e9e"
                app:pageColor="#ffeaeaea"
                app:radius="5dp"
                app:snap="true" />

            <com.abc.app.classes.LoadMoreListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_mainNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="20dp"
                android:fadingEdge="none"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/xcv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lst_mainNews"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Load More"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/pager_urgent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#E41F1F"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fadingEdge="none" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/costum_progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### Edit 2

gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/PhotoView.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library-recyclerview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'eu.inmite.android.lib:android-styled-dialogs:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any `InflateException`?

Comment: post home.xml of fragment '

Comment: can you also post `build.gradle` of your app?

Comment: @RohitArya : Done...

Comment: @FahimParkar, did it work after changing the support lib version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/218):

trying changing:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

Comment: checking... give me some time